# Python: How do you code drag and drop base color to emission color?

Tags: python, materials, emission

You can select the base color swatch of any BSDF and drag it down to the emission color.  This will paste the HSV values.  This produces a nice, fast, emission effect.  For a while now, I have been trying to duplicate this action with Python but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any ideas about the Python script to describe that action?

I have tried to script an add on.  The action is part of a "light switch" like functionality for selected objects.  It does not perform as expected.

```
     import bpy
from mathutils import Vector, Color

class MYADDON_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "MYADDON_PT_Panel"
    bl_label = "My Addon Panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "My Addon"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        light_switch = context.scene.light_switch

        layout.prop(light_switch, "toggle_box")

class MyAddonProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    toggle_box: bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name="Toggle Box",
        description="Toggle the emission material of selected objects",
        default=False,
        update=lambda self, context: LightSwitch.toggle_emission_material(context.active_object.material_slots[0].material, context.scene.light_switch.toggle_box) if context.active_object is not None and len(context.active_object.material_slots) > 0 and context.active_object.active_material is not None else None,
    )

class LightSwitch(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.toggle_emission_material"
    bl_label = "Toggle Emission Material"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None and context.active_object.active_material is not None

    @staticmethod
    def toggle_emission_material(material, toggle_box):
        if material is None:
            return
        for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            for slot in obj.material_slots:
                mat = slot.material
                if mat == material:
                    if toggle_box:
                        # Get the base color of the material (input 0)
                        base_color = material.node_tree.nodes.get('Principled BSDF').inputs[0].default_value
                        # Set the emission color (input 0) to the base color
                        material.node_tree.nodes.get('Emission').inputs[0].default_value = base_color
                        # Set emission strength to 3
                        material.node_tree.nodes.get('Emission').inputs[1].default_value = 3.0
                    else:
                        # Set emission color to black (0,0,0,1)
                        material.node_tree.nodes.get('Emission').inputs[0].default_value = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
                        # Set emission strength to 0.0
                        material.node_tree.nodes.get('Emission').inputs[1].default_value = 0.0

classes = [MYADDON_PT_Panel, LightSwitch, MyAddonProperties]

def register():

    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    
    bpy.types.Scene.light_switch = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyAddonProperties)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MYADDON_PT_Panel)
    
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    
    del bpy.types.Scene.light_switch
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: you mean copying the base color of principled bsdf to its emission color? what have you tried that does not work?

Comment: ok, I'm not sure about which information you're looking for? Know how to find the material? the node in it, or its inputs?

Comment: Sorry lemon, just updating my question.  I run the script and it doesn't change the emission properties of the selected objects.

Comment: OK. Is it about setting the Emission input of the principled or getting another Emission node? If another node (and if this node exists), your script should work (and it works)

Comment: Question is about the changing the emission color to be the same as the base color of a given material.  (After checking a toggle box would be a nice extra.)

Comment: What you have done works: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8v2l.gif you just need to have the good shader settings... Or do you want to change the "emission" input of the principled?

Comment: Thank you for demonstrating that.  I didn't realize the script would function if I set up the nodes in the shader editor. (!)   I wanted the script to work just with the principled in material properties.

Comment: Hello ! I don't think you need an operator class to fire the update callback. This is a bit weird to see and I would advise you to not do it. If you want to call an operator this is not the method, and I would also advise not calling operators in property callback methods.

Comment: You can also change the callback, `self` contains the property group object so you can access the toggle with `self.toggle_box` in the lambda instead of `context.scene.light_switch.toggle_box` which also brings the risk of not using the correct property group if your file has more than one scene.

Comment: BTW the two `for` loops and `if mat == material:` are superfluous here, material data is shared among objects so if you modify one material, you'll modify all instances of it across all objects in the file. You can `if toggle_box:` directly after testing if your material is not None.

Comment: Thanks Gorgious, appreciate the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, thank you for clarifying your question.

Using it with principled only, you can change this part of the script like so:

```
        if mat == material:
            principled = material.node_tree.nodes.get('Principled BSDF')
            if toggle_box:
                # Get the base color of the material (input 0)
                base_color = principled.inputs[0].default_value
                # Set the emission color (input 0) to the base color
                principled.inputs[19].default_value = base_color
                # Set emission strength to 3
                principled.inputs[20].default_value = 3.0
            else:
                # Set emission color to black (0,0,0,1)
                principled.inputs[19].default_value = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
                # Set emission strength to 0.0
                principled.inputs[20].default_value = 0.0
```

To know the inputs of a node, you can, in Python console:

[image]

Inputs can also be accessed by their names. For example `principled.inputs['Emission']` instead of `principled.inputs[19]`.

[image]

Comment: I've attached a blend file, in case of...

Comment: I got it right before you sent the blend.  Thanks lemon, well done.